# creating complex structure

Tags: wordpress, civimember

1> Is it possible in civicrm to create a structure where . there is a main Branch this BRANCH has 4-5 sub branches BRANCH1,BRANCH2,BRANCH3,BRANCH4,BRANCH5 each of sub branches has 4-5 membership type.

2> what type should i mention for custom fields like 'RESEARCHING SCHOLAR LINKS' where somebdy was member of Branch1 and new member is trying to be member of branch 2,.

3>what should be the content type be given to custom fields so that relationships can be easily created/established.

Comment: There are various ways of creating a branch structure but it depends on how you want to use them.  For example, do you just need membership to show as belonging to a branch?  Do you need staff of a branch to only see their own members etc?  If you can expand on what you want to achieve with branches that would help.

Comment: Aidan raises a good question - do you need 'memberships' between an individual and a branch - or would a relationship suffice

Comment: Aidan @petednz - fuzion, thanks for the replies .
i need membership between an individual with branch type of structure , Like i mentioned there is an org. say BRANCH , which has 2-3 sub branches say BRANCH1 ,BRANCH2, BRANCH 3.each of sub branches offer there own memberships. 
for the long run i need to have the data everything like who joined branch1 with which membership ,his history etc.,

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible in civicrm to create a structure where there is a main Branch this BRANCH has 4-5 sub branches BRANCH1, BRANCH2, BRANCH3, BRANCH4, BRANCH5 each of sub branches has 4-5 membership type.

Yes - just make a Membership Type and set each of the sub-Branches as the 'Organisation' for that Memb Type

> what type should i mention for custom fields like 'RESEARCHING SCHOLAR LINKS' where somebdy was member of Branch1 and new member is trying to be member of branch 2,.

Probably a Contact Reference field

> what should be the content type be given to custom fields so that relationships can be easily created/established.

Relationships do not have anything to do with Custom Fields. You can use Contact Reference custom fields to link one Contact to another, but it is more common to use Relationship Types